# How to get TCP PORT Oracle Server with SQL statment

Tags: sql, oracle, port

In Microsoft SQL Server I get TCP Port with this statment:

```
select CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port;
```

> 1433

How to get TCP PORT with SQL statment in Oracle Server?

Comment: The port is available only for the listener, and not for the database. Use 'show parameter local_listener' to get the configuration of the listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't. There's no *select statement* you could run which would reveal that information.

From the command prompt, you could try with `tnsping`, e.g.

```
c:\Temp>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-STU-2
020 21:38:22

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\lf\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lflaptop)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (20 msec)                                                                             ----
                                                                                     here it is
c:\Temp>
```

Or, you could ask your DBA, they know.

Comment: and is it possible to do that by SQL statements?

Comment: As I said & as far as I know, **no**, @Fabián.

Comment: "and is it possible to do that by SQL statements?"  You seem resistant to asking your DBA a very simple question.  Why is it so important that you get this information from a SQL query?  BTW, if you were able to get it from a SQL query, then you would actually already know it - you would have had to know it in order to connect to the database to issue the query in the first place.